# ImageView not keeping state when screen rotates in Android

Tags: android

Consider a layout  has  one EditText and one Image View. We type something in EditText and select an image from Gallery and attach the image to ImageView. After that we rotate the screen,  the imageview will lose its view but the EditText will keep its state.

Answer (score 0):

Use below line in your manifest file of activity which has imageview.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```